# Redoing home page but changes not taking effect

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey guys I am in the process of making a WordPress website mobile responsive and I decided to utilize bootstrap. I successfully implemented the changes to the nav menu and hero section but this section here:
[image]

I want to replace it with a bootstrap mobile responsive version which I did with this:

```
?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="container index">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Welcome to Three Green Birds!</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                                <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

                                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


                                    <div class="date"><span class="month"><?php the_time('M d') ?></span><span class="year">.<?php the_time('y') ?>.d<?php the_time('z') ?>/w<?php the_time('W') ?></span></div>
                                    <!--<div class="spacer"></div>-->
                                <div class="post-title">
                        <?php if (function_exists('get_cat_icon')) get_cat_icon('class=myicons'); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                                    <div class="spacer"></div>
                                    <div class="post-content">
                                    <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="spacer"></div>
                                    <div class="postmeta"><span class="postcat"><b>Categories:</b> <?php the_category(', ') ?>
                                    <?php the_tags('| <b>Tags:</b> ', ', ', ''); ?>
                                    | <b>Comments:</b> <?php comments_popup_link('0', '1', '%', '', 'Off'); ?></span>
                                  <span class="postcat"><?php edit_post_link('| <b>Edit</b>'); ?></span>
                                    </div>   
                                    <div class="post-footer"></div>

                                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                                <div class="navigation">
                                <br/><br/>
                                    <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
                                    <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
                                </div>

                            <?php else : ?>

                                <div class="post-title">Not Found</div>
                                <p class="post-content">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
                                <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/searchform.php"); ?>

                            <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <?php if (is_active_sidebar('sidebar')) : ?>
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <hr>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2008-2017 Three Green Birds. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </footer>
    </div>





<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But despite the fact that I emptied cache repeatedly, restarted MAMP, the old code will not go away. Is this because I have not made any changes to the CSS yet to go with the bootstrap html tags?

Here is the functions.php file to view the css and js scripts properly enqueued:

```
<?php
    // Theme Support
    function tgb_theme_support(){
        // Nav Menus
        register_nav_menus(array(
            'primary'   => __('Primary Menu')
        ));
    }

    add_action('after_setup_theme', 'tgb_theme_support');

    function bootstrap_css_js(){

        wp_enqueue_style('bootcss', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'stylecss', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), false, 'screen' );
        wp_enqueue_script('bootjs', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/main.js', array('jquery'), true);
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootjs', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), true );
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap_css_js');
```

Comment: Did you properly enqueue the Bootstrap CSS and JavaScript?

Comment: Hi, are you sure you are modifying the proper file? Home.php? Front-page.php? Maybe index.php?

Comment: @JackJohansson, you had the correct answer. I was modifying index.php when I should have been modifying sidebar.php and page.php. If you like you can post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are not editing the proper template file. Editing the home page can be a bit tricky in WordPress, some times. WordPress uses different templates depending on the situation to render the home. These templates can be:

```
front-page.php // Overrides all
home.php // For latest posts
page.php // For static pages as homepage
index.php // If none of the above exist
```

There is a good post [here](https://www.rarst.net/wordpress/front-page-logic/) by @Rarst, deeply explaining the hierarchy.

Also, you can check the [WP-Hierarchy](http://wphierarchy.com/) Out for further information.